# reload page with XMLHTTPREQUEST POST response

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

i have an XMLHTTPREQUEST, and the request returns me a string with an HTML page that i want to charge on the page (the HTML contains Js and CSS) but i dont know how to do this. Here is my code:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){
      if (xhr.readyState ===4){
        if (xhr.status ===200){
            try{
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if(data.success){
                //.......here i obtain the HTML with xhr.repsonse;
                }else{
                    toastAlert(1,data.msg_response);
                }
            }
            catch{
                console.log("......")
            }
        }else{
            toastAlert(1,"......");
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Does it contain a string of the URL to the page or the entire page's HTML as a string?

Comment: is the entry page as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` property of DOM element to set have the response string parsed and added to DOM.

MDN Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Example:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<div>XHR Response...</div>';
```

This approach will not do a full page refresh, but it will allow you to do some basic page content reloading using AJAX. I encourage you to take a look at Turbolinks project: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Cheers.

Comment: I think on this but i need some more like `form.submit()`, after you do that, the page reloads with the response.

Comment: You can use `location.href` or `location.reload` to force full page reload, but I think you are doing something wrong here. You shouldn't be using ajax if you expect page to do a full refresh after the response is returned. AJAX enables you to do quite the opposite – send a request without reloading a page.

Comment: Oh i see, my concepts on this are not clear yet, so if it is not possible i need to refactor the method, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to up vote if you find the answer relevant and helpful. :)